C language pattern with unexpected result
I am trying to create a program in C to draw this pattern :
1 1 2 1 3 1
1 2 2 2 3 2
1 3 2 3 3 3
1 4 2 4 3 4
1 5 2 5 3 5

I checked the answer from solutions.
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    
    for (i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1 ; j <= 3 ; j++)
        {
            printf("%i %i",j,i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;

but I can't understand why this code (Above) gives the previous result instead of this result :
1 2 3 1
1 2 3 2
1 2 3 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5


Start with explaining to us and to yourself what exactly the required pattern represents.

The pair columns contain the column number, the odd columns contain the line number. So you basically need to have a test (like if (column is pair) {print something} else {print something else}).

BTW, if you give your variables meaningful names (like e.g. line and column instead of i and j, the whole problem suddenly becomes much easier.

@Jabberwocky: Confusion between i and j is not the issue here.

@EricPostpischil I didn't write that, but it's probably just easier for a beginner (actually for anyone) to write code with meaningful variable names.

1 2 3 1
1 2 3 2
1 2 3 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5

This output would appear if each iteration of the inner loop printed the value of j (1, 2, 3), and then, just after the inner loop, the value of i were printed. However, that is not what the code says. The inner loop contains printf("%i %i",j,i);, and that prints two numbers each time it is called, one for j and one for i.
To print the value for i separately after all the values for j, you would need a separate printf, as in:
    for (i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1 ; j <= 3 ; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ", j);
        }
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }


The inner loop will be executed 3 times and in every step it will print out 2 numbers. So the first line is:
1 1 2 1 3 1

j counts from 1 to 3, while i is fix to 1.
Does this help for the next lines?
